# How to manually wipe out workspaces used in a Jenkins pipeline from the web UI with Blue Ocean?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a Jenkinsfile with Blue Ocean.

For a traditional jenkins project, it's workspace can be wiped out manually from the project page (Wipe out Current Workspace).

Where is the same feature when jenkins pipeline is used? It seems that deleteDir() can be used in pipeline to wipe out a workspace, but I still cannot do it manually from Jenkins web page.